# Reference the Community Nav Menu inside a lightning Component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-community, navigation

I would like to reference the native community nav menu and profile menu from one of my lightening components. However when i tried, it did not call the menu.

Is there a syntax that i am missing to reference the community nav menu?

I tried the following which normally would work in a theme type lightening component of pge.

```
<aura:component description="MyCommunityNav" implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
<aura:attribute name="profileMenu" type="Aura.Component[]" required="false"/>
<aura:attribute name="navBar" type="Aura.Component[]" required="false"/>
<div>
{!v.profileMenu} 
</div>
<div>
 {!v.navBar}
</div>
```

Is it even possible to reference the Community Nav Bar from Lightening Component that is Not a theme component?

Answer (score 0):

With the limited info provided and what I understood, It looks like you are asking about creating a navBar Lightning component that you can then use to drag and drop in your buidler, the answer is No, this is not possible today.

In order to use a navBar Component, you must use a `forceCommunity:themeLayout` Interface.

Notice that different interface will allow/support instantiation of certain components, attributes and events.

For more on Interfaces, you can refer to:

> [Interfaces](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.212.0.lightning.meta/lightning/oo_interfaces.htm?search_text=implements) from the lightning component developer guide.